# Making use of the Android GPU debugging tools

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es2, android-studio

I tried following the manual to install the Android GPU debugging tools for android Studio 2.0. Unfortunately it has not been very successful.
I have been following the instructions of the official documentation which are still for version 1 of the gpu debugging tools here: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/gpu-profiler
It also isn't that helpful otherwise.

I am using an arm based emulator for testing since the abi specific folders specified in the manual are for arm abi's only.
Also the red button above the gpu monitor that is used to start the debugging tools is grayed out for me and it tells me that the gpu debugging tools are not installed when I hover over it.

Are there any extra steps I need to follow to get it to work?